# Calculate variation of IP addresses column using MySQL

Tags: mysql, ip, ip-address, standard-deviation, variance

I'm trying to detect people using proxies to abuse my website.

Often they will change proxies and so forth. But there is definitely a pattern of them using one proxy address many times. Much more than is normal for legitimate visitors.

Usually most accessing of my website is by unique ip addresses that have only visited once or a few times. Not repeatedly.

Let's say I have these ip addresses in a column:

```
89.46.74.56
89.46.74.56
89.46.74.56
91.14.37.249
104.233.103.6
```

That would mean there are 3 uniques out of 5. Giving a "uniqueness score" of 60%.

How would I calculate this efficiently using MySQL?

Comment: can you post sample table structure and data. with desired output

Comment: @amdixon ok, I think I've simplified the question and added some sample data :)

Comment: so as output : 89.46.74.56.....60%, 91.14.37.249......20%, 104.233.103.6......20% ?

Comment: @amdixon an overall score for the entire column

Comment: overall score representing the maximum of ( 60%, 20% and 20% ) ?

Comment: @amdixon if 60% of the ip addresses are unique, then the score for the column would be 60%. Only 1 number is returned - not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**plan**

> - get count grouping by ip
> - divide by ( cross-joining ) the total rowcount
> - take maximum repeat ratio from above

**setup**

```
create table example
(
  id integer primary key auto_increment not null,
  ip varchar(13) not null
);

insert into example
( ip )
values
( '89.46.74.56'   ),
( '89.46.74.56'   ),
( '89.46.74.56'   ),
( '91.14.37.249'  ),
( '104.233.103.6' )
;
```

**query**

```
select max(repeat_factor)
from
(
select ip, count(*) / rc.row_count as repeat_factor
from example
cross join ( select count(*) as row_count from example ) rc
group by ip
) q
;
```

**output**

```
+--------------------+
| max(repeat_factor) |
+--------------------+
| 0.6                |
+--------------------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbf98/5)**

Comment: Works perfectly - genius! Some people are just too good as SQL......I surrender to you. Will accept when it allows me to :)

Comment: I should mention that it is giving the opposite of what I originally asked in the question (1-uniqueness_score)......but it's all the same really......my fault for writing a question that could be taken either way.....thanks :)

Comment: no worries - glad it works for you, sometimes the semantics between these statistical `scores` are tricky to explain