# Calculate variation of IP addresses, within sighted accounts, using MySQL

Tags: mysql

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545944/calculate-variation-of-ip-addresses-column-using-mysql) the awesome [amdixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370847/amdixon) was able to come up with a query to calculate the level of repetition of IPs.

I've adapted this to look at specific accounts using `WHERE earning_account_id = ?`:

```
SELECT MAX(repeat_factor)
FROM
(
SELECT earning_ip, count(*) / rc.row_count AS repeat_factor
FROM earnings
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS row_count FROM earnings WHERE earning_account_id = ?) rc
WHERE earning_account_id = ?
GROUP BY earning_ip
) q
```

However, now I want to add an additional level of security.

I want to apply the same sort of query. But instead of limiting it to an earning_account_id, I want to limit it to any account grouping that has a sighting of a specific ip address.

This is so I can have better global detection of proxy spam, if they use multiple alt accounts.

Please note that I will no longer be limiting the query using `WHERE earning_account_id = ?`

So in other words if the ip_address was "45.55.80.86"

```
+--------------------+-------------+---------------------------+
| earning_account_id | earning_ip  | select row for repeat_factor query?|
+--------------------+-------------+---------------------------+
|                  1 | 45.55.80.86 | YES                       |
|                  1 | 45.55.80.86 | YES                       |
|                  2 | 1.22.83.65  | NO                        |
|                  2 | 91.15.76.37 | NO                        |
|                  3 | 45.55.80.86 | YES                       |
|                  4 | 61.25.76.37 | YES                       |
|                  4 | 1.22.83.65  | YES                       |
|                  4 | 45.55.80.86 | YES                       |
|                  5 | 61.25.76.37 | NO                        |
+--------------------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

The value to be returned would be the repeat_factor for all earnings of this ip, **but ignoring all accounts that have never included this ip address**.

In other words, what I'm trying to find out is:

> "how repetitive is this IP address within all accounts, but looking
>   only at the accounts where this IP address has been sighted?"

Comment: What does sighted mean?

Comment: Sighted means that the IP was used in a row containing that earning_account_id

Comment: Basically I have a group of people cooperating to form a botnet of sorts. I want to identify them using my reapeat_factor algorithm. But if I apply the query to my entire table then they get lost in the haystack. If I target my query just to accounts where the IP has been sighted I get a much better measure of how repetitively this IP has been used....

Comment: Some douchebag downvoted me because I didn't accept his answer :(

Comment: What would the desired result set look like?

Comment: @Strawberry I seem to remember your name from helping me in the past! Sorry but this time Zsolt seems to have beaten you to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

With an idea taken from [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query) and the answer from @SteveChambers, we can simplify this even further.

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN earning_ip = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(*)
FROM earnings WHERE earning_account_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT earning_account_id FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = ?
)
```

This also gives `0.6667` using the example IP `45.55.80.86`.

I leave the original answer here as parts of that might be useful for another queries.

**Original Answer**

By modifying the sub-queries and working my way up, the following would return the IDs for a given IP.

```
SELECT earning_account_id
FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = ?
GROUP BY earning_account_id
```

In case of the example where the IP is `45.55.80.86`, the query would return `1, 3, 4`.

Then count the occurrences of the given IP by IDs.

```
SELECT earning_account_id, count(earning_ip) AS occurrence
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_account_id IN (
    SELECT earning_account_id
    FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = ?
    GROUP BY earning_account_id
) AND earning_ip = ?
GROUP BY earning_account_id
```

In case of the example, this would return `1 => 2, 3 => 1, 4 => 1`

Then also count the number of all IPs for these IDs and join this with the previous result.

```
SELECT e.earning_account_id, count(e.earning_account_id) AS ip_count, o.occurrence
FROM earnings e
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT earning_account_id, count(earning_ip) AS occurrence FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_account_id IN (
        SELECT earning_account_id FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = ?
        GROUP BY earning_account_id
    ) AND earning_ip = ?
    GROUP BY earning_account_id
) o
WHERE e.earning_account_id = o.earning_account_id
GROUP BY e.earning_account_id
```

In case of the example, all IPs by account are `1 => 2, 3 => 1, 4 => 3`.

Finally, divide the sum of all occurrences with the sum of all IPs in this subset of rows.

```
SELECT sum(q.occurrence) / sum(q.ip_count) FROM (
    SELECT e.earning_account_id, count(e.earning_account_id) AS ip_count, o.occurrence
    FROM earnings e
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT earning_account_id, count(earning_ip) AS occurrence FROM earnings
        WHERE earning_account_id IN (
            SELECT earning_account_id FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = ?
            GROUP BY earning_account_id
        ) AND earning_ip = ?
        GROUP BY earning_account_id
    ) o
    WHERE e.earning_account_id = o.earning_account_id
    GROUP BY e.earning_account_id
) q
```

In case of the example, this would return `0.6667`, which corresponds to `4` occurrences in the `6` rows marked as `YES` above.

Comment: I'll award the bounty in 18 hours when it lets me

Answer (score 2):

The rows to be selected can be obtained simply enough:

```
select e.*
from example e
join 
(select distinct earning_account_id
 from example
 where ip = '45.55.80.86') subq
on e.earning_account_id = subq.earning_account_id;
```

At this point, if it was a SQL Server database you could simply bundle this into a Common Table Expression (CTE) and use its alias instead of the two references to the table name in [amdixon's query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545944/calculate-variation-of-ip-addresses-column-using-mysql#34546791). Unfortunately [MySQL doesn't provide such a luxury](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833535/how-to-transform-a-mssql-cte-query-to-mysql#8833676) so we are confined to subqueries, each of which must have a unique alias - so a bit uglier but this does the job:

```
select max(repeat_factor)
from
(
select ip, count(*) / rc.row_count as repeat_factor
from
(select e.*
 from example e
 join 
 (select distinct earning_account_id
  from example
  where ip = '45.55.80.86') subq
 on e.earning_account_id = subq.earning_account_id) cte1
cross join ( select count(*) as row_count from 
(select e.*
 from example e
 join 
 (select distinct earning_account_id
  from example
  where ip = '45.55.80.86') subq
 on e.earning_account_id = subq.earning_account_id) cte2
) rc
group by ip
) q;
```

See **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e196a/13)**